# How to access 'global' variable from subpackage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging

I am currently trying to ship some bigger project. That is the reason why I decided to use submodules. Take a look at the project structure:

```
/sandbox              
    __init.py__
    constants.py

    /sub1
        __init__.py
        foo.py
```

In my `constants.py` file, I have declared a single global variable:

```
MYGLOBAL = 42
```

I want to use its value in `foo.py`. This file has 2 functions for testing:

```
def foofunc():
    return 'I am foo.'

def constfunc():
    return 'I am {MYGLOBAL}.'
```

Also, I put this code into `/sandbox/sub1/__init__.py`:

```
from .foo import *
from sandbox.constants import *
```

Now, when I use my interpreter, I try to use both functions like this:

```
>> import sandbox.sub1
>> sandbox.sub1.foofunc()
'I am foo.'
>> sandbox.sub1.MYGLOBAL
42
>> sandbox.sub1.constfunc()
NameError: name 'MYGLOBAL' is not defined
```

To my understanding, the global variable is in the same namespace as the functions, but somehow the function does not see it.

How can I access it? Python version is 3.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"Global" variables are not really global in Python, and are only available in the namespace of the modules in which they're defined.

You should import `constants` in `foo.py` so that `MYGLOBAL` can be made available as an attribute of the `constants` module object:

```
from sandbox import constants
def constfunc():
    return f'I am {constants.MYGLOBAL}.'
```

Comment: Thank you, so I suppose I misunderstood the purpose of the ``__init__.py`` files. I tried to utilize them similar to header files in cpp. Is there a rule of thumb of what to put in there and what not?

Answer (score 0):

A late answer to this very nice question (upvoted).

Here is one thing that will give you a better understanding of what is going on:

```
>>> sandbox.sub1.constfunc.__module__
'sandbox.sub1.foo'

>>> sandbox.sub1.constfunc.__globals__['MYGLOBAL']
KeyError: 'MYGLOBAL'

>>> sandbox.sub1.foo.MYGLOBAL = 5

>>> sandbox.sub1.constfunc.__globals__['MYGLOBAL']
5

>>> sandbox.sub1.constfunc()
'I am 5'
```

In other words,

> "which module does this function actually belong in, and thus looks at to decide what module-global variables are available to it?"

You erroneously assumed it would be `sandbox.sub1`, but it's actually `sandbox.sub1.foo`. The reason is because the function's "parent module" is carried with the function object, even when this function object is copied to another module's "workspace".

With this understanding, there are several things you can do. One is as per the other answer here. An alternative solution might be to do this in `__init__.py`:

```
from . import foo
from .. import constants
foo.MYGLOBAL = constants.MYGLOBAL
```

etc.

Interesting things to note:

1. One thing to note is that the `from X import Y as Z` syntax is effectively equivalent to saying `Z = X.Y`. The reason this is an important insight is because it helps you realise that Z is not a 'reference' per se: **if you change X.Y, Z will not automatically get updated**.

   If you change the Y in X to another value, and you want to update Z, you need to reimport it with the "from X import Y as Z" syntax.
2. Interestingly, you cannot simply do:

   ```
   sandbox.sub1.constfunc.__module__ = sandbox.constants
   ```

   and simply expect to 'replace' the function's module-global variables to those of `sandbox.constants`. There reason for this seems to be that the `constfunc.__module__` attribute is simply a 'copy' of the original parent module, and changing it does not affect the actual parent module bound to the function (i.e., it does not dynamically 'rebind' the function to another module; though, since this is an internal variable, it may change in future python versions. Who knows. Don't rely on it.).

   Also, the `__module__` attribute is not used to create the `constfunc.__globals__` dictionary for the function; this always seems to reflect the global dictionary of the 'parent module' directly. So simply replacing the `sandbox.sub1.constfunc.__module__` variable doesn't automatically replace the `constfunc.__globals__` dictionary, but updating `sandbox.sub1.foo` does.